# What does 'pre'-allocating of a pointer, yet to be used, mean?

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management

I'm storing some unknown-sized data in a global `unsigned char` pointer-variable, doing this in a function. After having successfully stored the data, I actually can tell the data size. If so, do I need to reallocate the pointer with the actual pointer size?
The pointer is allocated at first with `p = malloc(sizeof(unsigned char));` for workability reason. Without that I get seg fault, but I don't understand exactly why this is necessary.

Example:

```
static void func();
unsigned char *p;
int p_size=0;

 int main() 
{
  p = malloc(sizeof(unsigned char));     // Why exactly is this necessary?

  func();

  /* everything is fine - so do I need reallocation of p 
   with now knowing the size p_size ?*/
  p = realloc( p , p_size * sizeof(unsigned char));

  return 0;
}

static void func(){

/*if reallocating p and p_size <= 13, i get heap corruption; 
"realloc():invalid next size:..." Otherwise if not reallocating p 
 I get no errors and p_size is increasable as desired*/

  for(p_size; p_size <= 12; p_size++) 
    *(p + p_size) = 'A' + p_size;
}
```

As stated in comments, code works fine without any reallocation of the pointer - so does this means, I can store as many data as I like into the pointer without the need of reallocating the memory?

And why do I get a heap corruption when reallocating `p` and setting  `p_size <= 13` in the for loop and otherwise not?

Comment: Maybe a nit, but a serious source of confusion for some new C programmers: You are not storing unknown-sized data in a pointer variable. You're storing a pointer to such data. And you're not allocating or reallocating the pointer. You're allocating an object for it to point to, or reallocating the object it points to. These are important distinctions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are doing is very dangerous. You are allocating enough space for a single `unsigned char` which is 1 byte, and then you're writing an arbitrary amount of data. It's just luck that your program doesn't crash every single time. This is a [buffer overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow).

You need to allocate enough memory in advance to hold the data you're going to write. If you can't predict in advance, then you need to check during the `func()` call that you have enough room left, and if not then reallocate or abort.

Comment: s/luck/bad luck/. A program crashing early in development is almost always better than it crashing only in production.

Comment: What happens then if I would reallocate space after storing the data?

Answer (score 1):

Graham Borland's note about buffer overflow is correct. To answer your question, your code crashes in this line without malloc():

```
*(p + p_size) = 'A' + p_size;
```

It crashes because you are trying to dereference a NULL pointer here. *p is defined as a global variable and therefore is initialized to NULL automatically by compiler. If you use malloc before dereferencing *p is set to a correct value. Apart from this there are 2 more problems with your code:

- you should check if malloc succeeds
- if you define a function that takes no parameters you need to use void as a parameter in a prototype

Comment: Does the malloc() funtion dereferencing the NULL pointer, then? As I understand, after I malloced memory for the pointer I must reallocate memory of p_size and then dereference it during the function.

Comment: No, `malloc()` does not dereference a NULL pointer. It takes size and, if it doesn't fail, returns a valid pointer to void. A pointer returned by `malloc()` is assigned by a caller to a specified pointer. No explicit conversion is needed because pointers to void can be cast implicitly to pointers to other types in C (in contrary to C++).